# How to use the bootstrap 4 SASS mixins with customization in Angular 7 without importing multiple bootstraps

Tags: css, angular, sass, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

In my angular.json this is what I have

```
"styles": [
    "src/assets/styles.scss"
],
```

and in my styles.scss, I added my custom.scss

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap/scss/custom';
```

in my custom.scss, this is what I have

```
// custom 24 grid system
$grid-columns: 24;

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

In my SASS partials files, I can use the bootstrap 4 mixins without importing my custom.scss file but for a scss file that's coupled with an Angular component, I have to import custom.scss file like this to use any of the bootstrap 4 mixins.

```
@import 'vendor/bootstrap/scss/custom';
```

but if I do this, in my style sheet, I see bootstrap being imported twice. How can I avoid duplicate imports? I've tried to add my custom.scss straight to my angular.json file but that also duplicated the import.